# Can I subset a list of indexes and rows around the indexes?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large datatable and I want to reduce it based upon a list of indexes that I have (DT[index_vector]. 
Is there a way to not only subset the rows from the index_vector but also +- 5 rows around the indexes?

I'm trying to figure out if I really need to create a loop or there is a more efficient way to do the subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is

```
DT[sort(unique(sapply(index_vector, function(i) pmax(1, (i-5)):pmin((i+5), .N)))]
```

---

another option is `Map`

```
DT[unique(sort(pmin(pmax(1, unlist(Map(`:`, index_vector - 5, 
        index_vector + 5))), .N)))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've studied what pmin & pmax does and why sort and unique are needed. While the syntax is data.table, is there a way to use by? My islands that I cut into are not always centered so I end up cutting incorrectly. If I simply add the by, I get the error that there is nothing supplied in the j - but this is purely a row operation so I don't need to column operator.

Comment: works with dt<-dt[unique(sort(pmin(pmax(1, unlist(Map(:, indexes - 5, indexes + 5))), .N))),pass:=1, by=Grp_Col] and then dt<-dt[pass == 1]